# Noob Concern: T-SQL Group By Clause Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  This is a sample query from a T-SQL Fundamentals book that I am reading...

```
SELECT empid, orderdate FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE custid = 71
GROUP BY empid, YEAR(orderdate)
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'Sales.Orders.orderdate' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What the heck am I doing wrong?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` you provided is working off `empid` and the year of the orderdate (an INT).  But the `SELECT` is returning `empid` and a DATETIME data type...  Disregarding the data type, the data is different between what is being grouped & presented.

You need to use:

```
  SELECT o.empid, 
         YEAR(o.orderdate) 
    FROM Sales.Orders o
   WHERE o.custid = 71
GROUP BY o.empid, YEAR(o.orderdate)
```

...or:

```
  SELECT o.empid, 
         o.orderdate 
    FROM Sales.Orders o
   WHERE o.custid = 71
GROUP BY o.empid, o.orderdate
```

Alternately, SQL Server allows you to reference column aliases in the GROUP BY:

```
  SELECT o.empid, 
         YEAR(o.orderdate) AS yr
    FROM Sales.Orders o
   WHERE o.custid = 71
GROUP BY o.empid, yr
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT empid, YEAR(orderdate) FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE custid = 71
GROUP BY empid, YEAR(orderdate)
```

There's an excellent blog post that explains the error you were getting and why you were getting it, here - http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try something like that

```
SELECT * FROM Sales.Orders AS o
WHERE custid = 71
GROUP BY YEAR(o.orderdate)
```